# Problem accessing UMLS UTS web services in .NET

Tags: .net, ontology, medical

I am trying to write a small test application that uses the UMLS UTS web services in .NET
However all the methods in the UMLSKS service such as findCUIByNormWord, findCUIByNormString seem to be returning null. I have checked that the correct proxy ticket is being returned by the CAS authentication service.

```
        CASService.AuthorizationPortTypeClient CasClient = new AuthorizationPortTypeClient();
        UMLSKS.UMLSKSServicePortTypeClient UmlsKsClient = new UMLSKSServicePortTypeClient();
        string ticket = CasClient.getProxyGrantTicket("<my user name>", "<my password>");
        string proxyTicket = CasClient.getProxyTicket(ticket, "http://umlsks.nlm.nih.gov");
        string umlsVersion = UmlsKsClient.getCurrentUMLSVersion(new CurrentUMLSRequest() { casTicket = proxyTicket });
        ConceptIdGroup cidG = UmlsKsClient.findCUIByNormWord(new ConceptIdNormWordRequest() { casTicket = proxyTicket, release = umlsVersion, searchString = query });
```

Can anyone point out where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Duh! The ticket is issued per call. Everything is a-ok.